# Why do the Lagrange points lie only on the orbital plane of the two co-rotating bodies?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, celestial-mechanics, centrifugal-force

I could not find a detailed explanation of the fact that Lagrange points lie only on the orbital plane of the 2 co-rotating bodies. As per the wikipedia page calculations are [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_point).

There is no indication in the equations, as to the planar nature of the solution. Can someone shed some light on this topic? Or suggest a detailed pdf perhaps?

Comment: Just a side-note: Please try not to give the mobile version of the wikipedia page. I have provided the desktop version for now. The mobile links are generally discouraged.

Comment: Oh. Im sorry , i was using my tablet, so the mobile version must have come up as a default. I did not understand. Thank you

Comment: This is one you should think through until you get it for yourself, because it will empower you to see similar logic in other circumstances. Assume a position (*any* position) not in the main orbital plane, and consider the possible net direction of the sum of two gravities and the centrifugal pseudo-force. Can they sum to zero? How can you show that they can not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call the orbital plane of Earth and the moon the $xy$ plane, where $z=0$. Suppose you put a peanut at a hypothetical Lagrange point above the orbital plane, where $z>0$. Then the gravitational force from both Earth and the moon on the object has a negative $z$-component. IE, both gravitational forces pull the peanut back towards the orbital plane. The peanut will accelerate in the $-z$-direction. That means it couldn't have been in a Lagrange point to begin with, because being at a Lagrange point means the peanut needs to keep the same relative position.

If it isn't obvious that the force of gravity from both Earth and the moon has a negative $z$ component, consider the equation

$$\mathbf{F}_{grav} = -\frac{GMm}{r^2} \hat{r}$$

In this case $\hat{r}$ has a positive $z$ component because it points in the direction from Earth / moon (where $z=0$) to the peanut (where $z>0$). So with the minus sign in there, the force has a negative $z$ component.

Comment: Consider the earth and moon only, at A and B. I suggest an orbit (circular suppose), whose diameter is perpendicular to AB. That is , if i trace the surface produced By AP, where P is a satellite in the suggested orbit, it would be a cone. Isnt this possible? The centrifugal force of the rotating satellite will balance the net z component. And ofcourse the relative position of the satellite has symettry. Its at the same relative distance from A and B. Where is this wrong?

Comment: Neglect what is just said. I misunderdtood the term 'relative rest' . I must consider that to mean the poisition vector of the lagragian point to be fixed in space w.r.t A or B. I see my mistae.

Answer (score 2):

A Lagrange point is a point where a small object maintains a fixed position with respect to two large objects. The combined gravitational forces from the large objects cancels the centrifugal force felt by the small object.

Suppose a Lagrange point was to one side of the plane. Then it would stay that distance away. It would orbit in a plane parallel to the orbital plane. Centrifugal force would be parallel to the plane.

But both of the other masses would pull it toward the plane. The gravitational force is not parallel to the plane, and cannot balance that centrifugal force.